# Creating a carousel with bootstrap and handlebars

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap with handlebars to create a carousel. I'm getting specific items from my database that I want to show on the carousel.

At the moment, the carousel instead of going to the second slide, skips through it, and then the whole thing gets removed from the page.

The 2 test items being brought back from my database.

```
{ _id: 5d28ad4eec77e8389c56792b,
  slug: '5d28ad4eec77e8389c56792b',
  __v: 1,
  name: 'Test ',
  publishedDate: 2019-07-11T23:00:00.000Z,
  review: 'This was good',
  image: [ 5ce83014af97ea064c5a750d ] },{ _id: 5d29fab5c8a3794a081f65d6,
  slug: 'test2',
  name: 'test2',
  __v: 0,
  publishedDate: 2019-07-12T23:00:00.000Z,
  review: 'fdfsfdsdfsdfdsfsdfs',
  image: [] }
```

The carousel code

```
  <div class="container-fluid" id="anchorJump">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        {{#each testimonials}}
        {{#if @first}}
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="carousel-item active">{{{this.review}}}
            {{else}}
            <div class="carousel-item">{{{this.review}}}
              {{/if}}
              {{/each}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

carousel js code

```
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 6000,
    pause: "false",
    wrap:true
  });
```

Comment: Something looks off in your loop logic. Can you try removing the if statements and just loop the testimonials and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working. I think the issue is within the loop as mentioned in my comment

```
<script id='wrapper' type='text/x-handlebars-template'>
  <div >
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
     <div class="carousel-inner">
       {{#each testimonials}}
       <div class="item {{#if @first }}active {{/if}}">
         <div class="carousel-item {{#if @first }}active {{/if}}">{{this.review}}

           <div class="carousel-item">{{this.review}}


           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       {{/each}}      
     </div>
     </div>
</script>
```